# ActiveMQ not able to read the .jks file within a jar while creating connection

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to create an `ActiveMQSslConnection`. I have the truststore file (.jks) as part of a distributed jar. However, ActiveMQ is not able to read the file and throws `FileNotFoundException`. I verified the jar file and I do see the corresponding file, as in below structure.

`sample.jar`:

- META-INF
- com.sample.jms   -- Package
- sample.jks       -- File trying to load
- sample.properties

I ran the program in debug mode and see that ActiveMQ not able to find the file in jar. I changed the file path to outside jar and can read the file. 
To be precise it is at this below location in `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory`.

```java
protected InputStream getInputStream(String urlOrResource) throws IOException {
    try {
        File ifile = new File(urlOrResource);
        // only open the file if and only if it exists
        if (ifile.exists()) {  // **This condition failed**
            return new FileInputStream(ifile);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    InputStream ins = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlOrResource);
        ins = url.openStream();  //**Throwing exception here. Obviously could not find the file in jar.**
        if (ins != null) {
            return ins;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ignore) {
    }
    ...
}
```

I wonder why ActiveMQ is not using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` instead. I think that should possible work.

How can I fix this issue, by reading the .jks from within a jar?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since the version of ActiveMQ 5.x you're using apparently doesn't support the behavior you're looking for then I think the only way you could "fix this issue" at this point would be to modify the ActiveMQ source code and rebuild the broker.

You also might be able to simply upgrade to a later version of ActiveMQ as [it uses `getResourceAsStream`](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.java#L179):

```
protected InputStream getInputStream(String urlOrResource) throws IOException {
    try {
        File ifile = new File(urlOrResource);
        // only open the file if and only if it exists
        if (ifile.exists()) {
            return new FileInputStream(ifile);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    InputStream ins = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlOrResource);
        ins = url.openStream();
        if (ins != null) {
            return ins;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ignore) {
    }

    // Alternatively, treat as classpath resource
    if (ins == null) {
        ins = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(urlOrResource);
    }

    if (ins == null) {
        throw new IOException("Could not load resource: " + urlOrResource);
    }

    return ins;
}
```